# Benefit of using ng-container vs. template?

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript

In angular we could do:

```
template: `<ng-container #c></ng-container>`
```

or:

```
template: `<template #c></template>`
```

To create a view container that is hidden when the template is rendered.

Is there a difference between using `ng-container` over the html template alternative?  I'm guessing Angular has to have it's own template containers like `ng-template` or `ng-container` since use of the raw `html` template element could break non browser based runtimes, like mobile clients, etc.

Comment: who marked this question as primarily opinion based? It's not. There are differences between them. The first difference is that the equivalent of `template` HTML tag in angular is `ng-template` and not `ng-container`. And there are differences between `ng-container` and `ng-tempate`

Comment: @quirimmo the OP used the word "benefits" which tends to attract opinionated answers. So I edited the question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<ng-container>` is always rendered, but does not represent a DOM element. It is still attached to the component's view.

The `<ng-template>` will only be rendered if it is explicitly requested.

Here's a good reference on the subject:

http://nataliesmith.ca/blog/2018-05-01-ngtemplate-ngcontainer-ngcontent/

> To create a view container that is hidden when the template is rendered.

Always use `<ng-template>` when possible. The `<ng-container>` is for grouping DOM elements together. For example; when you need to apply a `*ngIf` to many `<td>` elements, because you can not use a `<span>` around `<td>`.

Comment: the `ng-template` is rendered if you use a template variable as for example `<ng-template #test>`

Comment: @quirimmo wouldn't it be rendered when the variable is referenced?

Comment: that's what I mean with "template variables". I think even the link you posted states the same, there is a dedicated example on it in the snippets

Comment: Great answer - thanks!  There is a 3rd type of template that can be used, which is the raw html `template` element.  I'm assuming that if that were to be used, it might break Angular's ability to generate views for different types of platforms ... native mobile ... etc?

Comment: @Ole Angular will render the `<template>` element as it is seen in the HTML template. The sameway it handles `<div>` or other tags.

Comment: @cgTag one of the things I was curious about is why Angular has it's own `template` like elements like `ng-template` and `ng-container` instead of using the raw html `template` element (Similar semantics to `ng-template`).  I think if we were to use that it might break rendering in non browser based runtimes?

Comment: I was reading through a few custom component articles, and one article used the html `template` element to create a dynamic component, and another used the `ng-container` element...so it made me question what the rationale would be for choosing one of the other.  I assume that using Angular's built in `ng-template` or `ng-container` is always better for flexibility reasons.

Comment: @Ole it would be a problem when you wanted `<template>` to behave like a normal HTML element. Example; if you used a third-party library that used `<template>` then you couldn't stop Angular from using it. So having `<ng-template>` is better, because Angular removes it from the DOM and replaces it with a comment.

Comment: @Ole `<template #c>` would make c a `ElementRef`, and `<ng-template #c>` would make c a `TemplateRef`. You can't pass ElementRef to the view factory methods. They require a TemplateRef.